# Calling multiple accessors in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to programming so bear with my ignorance.

Let's say I have a class called Name that simply takes one parameter

```
private $first;

public function __construct($f) {
    $this->first=$f;
}
```

I want to have two accessors for this: one that returns the first name just how it is given (so say getNameNormal()) and one that returns it in all upper case (so say getNameCaps()).

Is this possible? How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try creating those methods as part of your class?

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
class Name {
    private $first;

    public function __construct($f=null){
        if(!is_null($f)){
            $this->first = $f;
        }
    }

    public function getFirst(){
        return $this->first;
    }

    public function getUpperFirst(){
        return strtoupper($this->first);
    }
}
$n = new Name("test");
echo $n->getFirst().'<br>';
echo $n->getUpperFirst();
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/tdidmO

Answer (score 0):

A few different ways to do it, but you're on the right track.

```
public function getFirst(){
    return $this->first;
}

public function getFirstCaps(){
    return strtoupper($this->first);
}
```

or

```
public function getFirst($caps=false){
    if($caps){
      return strtoupper($this->first);
    }else{
      return $this->first;
    }
}
```